# Problems with anomalize function

Tags: r

I need to check the data array with function "Anomalize".

First I hooked up some libraries

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(anomalize)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(anytime)
```

Then I delete all column that i do not need for this task

```r
trash1 <- ASD[, -2]
trash2 <- trash1[,-2]
trash3 <- trash2[,-2]
trash4 <- trash3[,-2]
trash5 <- trash4[,-2]
trash6 <- trash5[,-2]
trash7 <- trash6[,-4]
trash8 <- trash7[,-4]
view(trash8)
```

Change class from Factor to Date:

```r
trash8$DMY <- as.Date(trash8$DMY, format="%d.%m.%y")
```

Than I tryed to anomalize this

```r
trash_tbl <- as_tibble(trash8)
trash_tbl %>%
  time_decompose(Qp) %>%
  anomalize(remainder) %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3 , alpha_dots = 0.5)
```

As the  result I have this error:

```r
Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = DMY
Note: Index not ordered. tibbletime assumes index is in ascending order. Results may not be as desired.
Error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date
```

Please help me with it or say, what can I read to solve that problem??

This is my data. DMY - Date, MCC - Factor, Art - Numeric, Qp - Numeric , Ql - Factor

```r
1    DMY        MCC      Art   Qp     Ql
1   2016-01-01 UA0000468 1801 3520    440
2   2016-01-01 UA0000468 3102 3024  604,8
3   2016-01-01 UA0000468 4419  270  521,1
4   2016-01-01 UA0000468 5537 1080 2084,4
5   2016-01-03 UA0010557 3528  180     36
6   2016-01-03 UA0010557 3529  198   39,6
...
```

Comment: From the `anomalize` manual, it appears you may not have properly converted your DMY data into the required format, i.e. "A tibble or tbl_time object."   Break your piped command sequence apart and check the class of each object produced at each step.